# How to view argument names in pycharm debugger console?

Tags: python, pycharm

Let's say I need to view the argument names in the editor, it's usually done with cmd/ctrl + p and here's the view:

[image: editor-view]

However when I try the same in the debugger console, I only get `*args, **kwargs`

[image: console-view]

How to change this behavior to be able to see the actual argument names?

Answer (score 0):

script path/Module name

Click the list to select a type of target to run. Then, in the corresponding field, specify the path to the Python script or the module name to be executed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).